# Burnt edges for a div using CSS3?

Tags: css

Is there a way I can get a non-conventional shape to a div like that of burnt sides or something similar using CSS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it with a border-image-source and other border-image-* properties, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-source